# Call function when we click the html button

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to call function in .cs file when we click the html button in aspx file.

Answer (score 2):

When you click on a button the OnClick handler function will be called:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" OnClick="BtnTestClick" Text="foo" />
```

When you click on the button the BtnTestClick function will be called:

```
protected void BtnTestClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a traditional "Postback" style ASP.net WinForms page, then create a method in your .aspx.cs file and attach it to the button, for example:

In .aspx file:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="myButton" OnClick="myButton_OnClick" Text="myButton" />
```

In .aspx.cs file:

```
protected void myButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // Code to act on button click goes here
}
```

Comment: <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" runat="server"   />

.cs file:
 public void display()
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
   
    }

How to call the display function which is in .cs file from html button click

Comment: If you want to acheive this, you should use button server control. I dont think this is acheivable in html button.

Comment: @sudha - See mine or Darin's answer. Or, do you have a specific reason for using a HTML button - i.e. is this a "mypage.htm", rather than "mypage.aspx"?

Answer (score 0):

Make the button an  and add a click event. This will post-back the page when you click it and call the function defined in the click event.