# how to Call cs function from html button

Tags: c#, asp.net

Html Button

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" runat="server"/>
```

.cs file:

```
public void display() 
{ 
Response.Redirect("default.aspx"); 
}
```

How to call the display function which is in .cs file from html button click

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551707/call-function-when-we-click-the-html-button

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551707/call-function-when-we-click-the-html-button. If you didn't get good responses in your original question, try editing it and provide more details there.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<asp:button>` instead and just bind the click event in the designer.
This will generate an input in the actual html.

Answer (score 0):

In your codebehind file use the following:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.ServerClick += display;
}
```

And change your display method signature to:

```
private void display(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
}
```